xfce desktop has limited permission
I have a newly installed debian 12 system. It runs xfce as it's default desktop UI. I login xfce with an account with sudo right. It seems the desktop UI has a general permission problem. I have the task panel at desktop top....

The right top corner icon I used to click to log out show reboot as un-clickable(grey). In my old debian 9 system I could.

When I plug in a flash drive, I used to be able to mount it by double click the icon on desktop (debian 9). But when I do the same operation in my new Debian 12 system, it complains that I am not authorized to do so.

Right top corner, I click the network manager icon try to connect a wifi network. It complains that "Not authorized to do the operation"


So even though my login account is a sudo user account, I still have permission issue? I have my account set to NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers
Anyone has a idea where I should tweak to fix this permission issue?

What's the output of pgrep polkitd?

I finally figured out what's going on...
Previously, I was trouble shooting Debian 12 xfce black screen after login issue. At that I suspected that my PAM authentication caused the issue. So I ran sudo pam-auth-update and unchecked the LDAP and register user session in the systemd control group hierarchy.
The black screen turned out caused by nvidia driver problem and was fixed after I installed the right driver. However, I forgot to change back the PAM thing. With that option unchecked, there are lots of thing that I can not do as a normal user even my account is in the sudo group. I can not mount a flash drive, my pulseaudio daemon does not run, I can not configure my wifi network, etc.
Once I reset the PAM auth options back to its original state, everything start to work. Except that I still can not get my sound card to work.
